# in python, how do you put a user's input into a pre-exsitsing list variable

Tags: python, user-input

## full section of code ex. here:

```
first, second, third, last =(input("test ")).split()
print("{0:s}{1:s}{2:s}{3:s}".format(last, third, second, first)))

User_guess=[0,0,0,0]
print(first)

User_guess.append[0]=first
```

## this code tells the user to input a sentence and print it out backwards. (while splitting each word)

```
first, second, third, last =(input("test ")).split()
print("{0:s}{1:s}{2:s}{3:s}".format(last, third, second, first)))

User_guess=[0,0,0,0]
print(first)

User_guess.append[0]=first
```

## this is the part where the problem occurs :line 13 in my prog. window...

```
User_guess.append[0]=first
```

.
.
.
(i am VERY tired and have no idea what to fix)
.
.
fYi, the variable User_guess links to a diffenrent part of the code that is affected by this.  BUT the other part does NOT effect this.

Comment: What is _this_ `User_guess.append[0]=first` supposed to mean???

Comment: supposed to add "first"  into the User_guess list (list is above the error line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User_guess` is already a list of 4 elements so no need to use `append()`. Use `User_guess[0]=first` to store the variable `first` into 0'th element of `User_guess` list.

Comment: thanks for the help. one other thing, if i wanted to compare the [0] in User_guess  with another randomly generated list, how would i write that?

Comment: I am not sure what comparison you are doing, but you can access the 0'th element through `User_guess[0]`.